# Rails installation - Ruby version mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-2.0

I was installing rails on my machine with RVM and Ruby 2.0.0 specified in Gemfile. When I run bundle install, I get the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

When I use `ruby -v`,  I see

```
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: comment out the `ruby 2.0.0` in **Gemfile**, insert instead of it `p RUBY_VERSION`, run `bundle exec rails s`, and show PATH env variable

Comment: I did what you said, but it used ruby version 1.9.3. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You didn't show the PATH

Comment: it seems that you've incorrectly set the rvm up

Comment: how about trying first: `rvm use . --install --create`

Answer (score 5):

It could be that your `bundle` command is not from the same Ruby as `ruby` is. Always check:

```
which ruby
which bundle
which gem
```

These might be completely different.

These can get out of sync if you install bundler on your system Ruby and then install something like `rbenv` or `rvm` on top of that without it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But after I set path to ruby, bundle, and gem commands to one directory, the problem still persits. Do you know any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove ruby from your Gemfile. Try

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
```

This o/p says that 1.9.3 is the default. This displays all the ruby versions present in your system. You can pick any of the versions which you want to use

$`rvm use version --default`.

Now

```
$ruby -v
```

This must match with the version you have set as default.